# How should I import this data into my database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, import

I have database with thousands of records

```
Code  | Name  | Price
00106 | Water | 9.99
00107 | Onion | 8.99
```

Which is coded in `GES` file like below:

- `00F` means column header
- `00I` means insert a row

there are also others like(`00D` for delete row or `00U` for update)

```
00F
0101
02Code
031
00F
0102
02Name
031
00F
0103
02Price
030
00I
0100106
02Water
030999
00I
0100107
02Onion
030899
```

I want to create importer which process this file and push it into my database. So I started implemented that:

```
class Importer
  CONN = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
  F = "00F"
  I = "00I"

  def extract_to_database(collection)
    add       = true
    tmp       = []
    type      = F
    inserts   = []

    collection.each_with_index do |line, i|
      _type    = line.strip
      _changed = [F,I].include? _type

      if _changed && i > 0
        case type
        when F then @f << tmp
        when I
          group_id = Group.find_by(code: tmp[1]).id
          inserts.push "(group_id,'#{tmp[2]}','#{tmp[3]}')"
        end

        tmp  = []
        type = _type
      end

      tmp << line
    end
    sql = "INSERT INTO products (`group_id`, `name`, `price`) VALUES #{inserts.join(", ")}"
    CONN.execute sql
  end
end
```

There is one problem with that, I would like to refactor that using functional programming.

And I will have to find other model by `code` and put to `products` table related `some_model_id` column so this can complicate whole process. Because right now importing this data takes me few hours.

Maybe using Ruby is not the best option.

Comment: Have you taken a look at what part of the process is the slowest. Maybe batch inserting sql and splitting up the file into multiple smaller versions and running them in parallel can help?

Comment: The slowest is finding each time group_id. I would like to do that in parallel but maybe you can show me how should I split that. Manually cut file by copy-paste ?

Comment: If group_id lookup is taking the most time, maybe you can dump the group id to a key value store like redis which gives your O(1) lookups. That may make things Faster. Also instead of inserting in the same loop, may be you can split the input into equal sized files and run them through a parser which spits out the sql inserts for each record. Then you can run the insert statements in bulk. Are there any update or delete operations as well?

Comment: Do you have an index on groups.code? if that's the slowest part, it could be an easy win.

Comment: Yep, Thanks this help me! I forgot to add it.

Comment: Whenever composing custom queries, be **very** careful not to sling in arbitrary user data without proper escaping. Remember that ActiveRecord has the [`sanitize_sql`](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods/sanitize_sql) method for escaping arbitrary statements with placeholders, or converting from Hash-style to SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing here that Ruby can't handle. It's not clear how "functional programming" would help this any, either, as this is a classic state-machine sort of problem with some simple data transformation going on.

Example scaffold:

```
class SomethingImporter
  FIELD_MARKER = "00F"
  INSERT_MARKER = "00I"

  COLUMNS = %w[ group_id name price ]

  # Performs the insert into a given model. This should probably be a class
  # method on the model itself.
  def bulk_insert(model, rows)
    sql = [
      "INSERT INTO `#{model.table_name}` (#{columns.collect { |c| }}"
    ]

    # Append the placeholders: (?,?,?),(?,?,?),...
    sql[0] += ([ '(%s)' % ([ '?' ] * COLUMNS.length).join(',') ] * rows.length).join(',')

    sql += rows.flatten

    model.connection.execute(model.send(:sanitize_sql, sql))
  end

  # Resolve a group code to a group_id value, and cache the result so that
  # subsequent look-ups for the same code are valid.
  def group_id(group_code)
    @find_group ||= { }

    # This tests if any value has been cached for this code, including one
    # that might be nil.
    if (@find_group.key?(group_code))
      return @find_group[group_code]
    end

    group = Group.find_by(code: group_code)

    @find_group[group_code] = group && group.id
  end

  # Call this with the actual collection, lines stripped, and with any header
  # lines removed (e.g. collection.shift)
  def extract_rows(collection)
    state = nil
    rows = [ ]
    row = [ ]

    collection.each_with_index do |line|
      case (line)
      when FIELD_MARKER
        # Indicates field data to follow
        state = :field
      when INSERT_MARKER
        case (state)
        when :insert
          rows << [ row[0], row[1], (row[2].sub(/^0+/, '').to_f / 100) ]
        end

        state = :insert
        row = [ ]
      else
        case (state)
        when :field
          # Presumably you'd pay attention to the data here and establish
          # a mapping table.
        when :insert
          row << line.sub(/^\d\d/, '')
          # puts row.inspect
        end
      end
    end

    case (state)
    when :insert
      rows << [ row[0], row[1], (row[2].sub(/^0+/, '').to_f / 100) ]
    end

    rows
  end
end


data = <<END
00F
0101
02Code
031
00F
0102
02Name
031
00F
0103
02Price
030
00I
0100106
02Water
030999
00I
0100107
02Onion
030899
END

importer = SomethingImporter.new

puts importer.extract_rows(data.split(/\n/)).inspect
```

The example output from this, based on your data, looks like:

```
[["00106", "Water", 9.99], ["00107", "Onion", 8.99]]
```

When writing code like this, be sure to expose *intermediate results* in order to be able to test what's happening. Your implementation takes data and dumps it directly in the database in one shot, making it very hard to tell where something's going wrong if it doesn't work out properly. This version is composed of several methods, each of which has a more specific purpose.

It's not clear in your original example why you're resolving `group_id` at all, your sample output has nothing to do with that, but as an example I've included a method that resolves them and keeps them cached, avoiding repeated lookups of the same thing. For a larger scale import you'd probably load in many rows, extract out the distinct group_id values, load them all at once, and remap them before inserting.